# Different date format for same column in Informatica IICS

Tags: date-format, informatica, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am getting data from rest API in JSON forma and have a scenario where a column can have multiple date format. The current date format could be either `2011-02-12T01:00:00` or `2020-04-15T20:44:57.38`or could be `null` or something else also.

I want to parse it through expression and trying to capture the full date string. The following expression seems to be working fine however it is truncating the millisecond part and returning value upto second only.

```
iif(isnull(%date_fields%),'\N',
to_char(To_date(to_char(%date_fields%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

But when I tried it with millisecond usinf below expression:

```
iif(isnull(%date_fields%),'\N',
to_char(To_date(to_char(%date_fields%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'))
```

It is throwing error:

```
TT_11132 Transformation [Expression3] had an error evaluating output column [JobStartDate_out]. 
Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date 
... t:TO_DATE(u:TO_CHAR(t:<02/12/2011 01:00:00>,u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS')].
```

I searched few option using below but getting parsing error.

```
DECODE (TRUE,
iff(isnull(%date_milli%),
'\N',
is_date(To_date(to_char(%date_milli%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
is_date(To_date(to_char(%date_milli%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'),
ERROR('NOT A VALID DATE')))
```

What could be the possible resolution to handle the multiple date format in Informatica? Here JSON date format is string and I am mapping it to date/time type and using Output Marco Fields to combine multiple similar column together.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you check both options - with and without milliseconds?
You can use below `iif` condition. Also i think your expression has some issues.
I assumed date_milli is a character type. If its a date, then you can change below expressions accordingly.

```
iff(isnull(%date_milli%),null,
iif( is_date(to_char(%date_milli%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date(to_char(%date_milli%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
iif( is_date(to_char(%date_milli%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS'), to_date(to_char(%date_milli%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS')
))
)
```

Comment: Date filed was string in Json and I am overwriting in mapping with date/time datatype. I am getting the parser error with this too. I tried this `iif(isnull(%date_fields%),'\N',
to_char(To_date(to_char(%date_fields%),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) ` which is working and I am looking something similar that can identify the type and write output

Comment: this will fail if you have some weird date format. if you add `is_date` check then it should work for all inputs. What is the error when you use this `'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS'` ?